# Replace part of string with variable with Regex(Regular expression) condition match javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6

I was thinking is possible to replace this condition match to a link in the map method.

The end goal, I want to replace address apt #number to be a link after it render.

But the address is wrap with all the text like this:
`Kulas Light Apt #556 Gwenborough 92998-3874` to be like:

`Kulas Light Apt ${variable} Gwenborough 92998-3874`

that variable contain a tag like this 
`<a href=${data.website}> ${parseInt(numberMatch)} </a>`

I don't know how can I just grab that number, and then turn to a link.

Thanks for the help!

```
const datas = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Leanne Graham",
  "username": "Bret",
  "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
  "address": "Kulas Light Apt #556 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
  "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
  "website": "hildegard.org",
  "company": {
    "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
    "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
    "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
  }
},
{
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Ervin Howell",
  "username": "Antonette",
  "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
  "address": "Kulas Light Apt #123 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
  "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
  "website": "anastasia.net",
  "company": {
    "name": "Deckow-Crist",
    "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
    "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
  }
},
{
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Clementine Bauch",
  "username": "Samantha",
  "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
  "address": "Kulas Light Apt #56 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
  "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
  "website": "ramiro.info",
  "company": {
    "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
    "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
    "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
  }
}
]

const testing = datas.map(data => {
  if (data.address.match(/[#][0-9]+/)) {
    let numberMatch = data.address.match(/[#][0-9]+/)
    numberMatch = `<a href=${data.website}> ${parseInt(numberMatch)} </a>`
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>id: {data.id}</p>
      <p>name: {data.name}</p>
      <p>address: {data.address}</p>
    </div>
  )
})
```

Comment: @ggorlen Apologize for the confusion, I update my question hope that make more sense now. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you could just use `replace`

```js
const datas = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": "Kulas Light Apt #556 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": "Kulas Light Apt #123 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": "Kulas Light Apt #56 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ramiro.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
    }
  }
]

const testing = datas.map(({
  id,
  name,
  address,
  website
}) => {
  return (
    `<div>
      <p>id: ${id}</p>
      <p>name: ${name}</p>
      <p>address: ${address.replace(/#\d+/, match => `<a href=${website}> ${match} </a>`)}</p>
    </div>`
  )
})
console.log(testing);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this at one time using `replace` method :

- the regular expression to be used is `/(apt)\s?#(\d+)/i`

  - `(apt)` *apt* literally, put in a group to be referenced later in the replacement string.
  - `\s?` a space if found.
  - `#` a *#* literally. If you want that to be matched and showed later in the kink's text, add it to the next capturing group.
  - `(\d+)` one or more digit. You could use `(#\d+)` if you want to include the hash sign (but remove the literal matching of it).
- the replacement string is `$1 <a href=${data.website}>$2</a>` :

  - `$1` returns the first capturing group which is *apt*.
  - `$2` returns the first capturing group which is the digits found after *apt #*.

```js
datas = [{
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Leanne Graham",
    "username": "Bret",
    "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
    "address": "Kulas Light Apt #556 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
    "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
    "website": "hildegard.org",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
      "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
      "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "name": "Ervin Howell",
    "username": "Antonette",
    "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
    "address": "Kulas Light Apt #123 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
    "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
    "website": "anastasia.net",
    "company": {
      "name": "Deckow-Crist",
      "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
      "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
    }
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "name": "Clementine Bauch",
    "username": "Samantha",
    "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
    "address": "Kulas Light Apt #56 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
    "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
    "website": "ramiro.info",
    "company": {
      "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
      "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
      "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
    }
  }
], newArr = datas.map(data =>
  `<div>
      <p>id: ${data.id}</p>
      <p>name: ${data.name}</p>
      <p>address: ${data.address.replace(/(apt)\s?#(\d+)/i, `$1 <a href=${data.website}>$2</a>`)}</p>
  </div>`
);

/** showing the first element in newArr **/
console.log(newArr[0]); 
/** output :
<div>
  <p>id: 1</p>
  <p>name: Leanne Graham</p>
  <p>address: Kulas Light Apt <a href=hildegard.org>556</a> Gwenborough 92998-3874</p>
</div>
*/
```

Answer (score 0):

When you are using **match()**, it is returning an object. So you have to get the value by fetching as you fetch from an array. Also, you are trying to convert the string starting with **"#"** through **[parseInt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt)** which is returning **"NaN"**. You can get your expected output through below code:

```js
const datas = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Leanne Graham",
  "username": "Bret",
  "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
  "address": "Kulas Light Apt #556 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
  "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
  "website": "hildegard.org",
  "company": {
    "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
    "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
    "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
  }
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Ervin Howell",
  "username": "Antonette",
  "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
  "address": "Kulas Light Apt #123 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
  "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
  "website": "anastasia.net",
  "company": {
    "name": "Deckow-Crist",
    "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
    "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
  }
  },
  {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Clementine Bauch",
  "username": "Samantha",
  "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
  "address": "Kulas Light Apt #56 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
  "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
  "website": "ramiro.info",
  "company": {
    "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
    "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
    "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
  }
  }
  ]

  let numberMatch
  const testing = datas.map(data => {
  if (data.address.match(/#[0-9]+/)) {
    numberMatch = data.address.match(/#[0-9]+/)
    let value = numberMatch.map(val => val)
    numberMatch = `<a href=${data.website}> ${value[0]} </a>`
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>id: {data.id}</p>
      <p>name: {data.name}</p>
      <p>address: {data.address}</p>
      <p>website: {numberMatch}</p>
    </div>
  )
 })
```

OR

```js
const datas = [{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Leanne Graham",
  "username": "Bret",
  "email": "Sincere@april.biz",
  "address": "Kulas Light Apt #556 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
  "phone": "1-770-736-8031 x56442",
  "website": "hildegard.org",
  "company": {
    "name": "Romaguera-Crona",
    "catchPhrase": "Multi-layered client-server neural-net",
    "bs": "harness real-time e-markets"
  }
  },
  {
  "id": 2,
  "name": "Ervin Howell",
  "username": "Antonette",
  "email": "Shanna@melissa.tv",
  "address": "Kulas Light Apt #123 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
  "phone": "010-692-6593 x09125",
  "website": "anastasia.net",
  "company": {
    "name": "Deckow-Crist",
    "catchPhrase": "Proactive didactic contingency",
    "bs": "synergize scalable supply-chains"
  }
  },
  {
  "id": 3,
  "name": "Clementine Bauch",
  "username": "Samantha",
  "email": "Nathan@yesenia.net",
  "address": "Kulas Light Apt #56 Gwenborough 92998-3874",
  "phone": "1-463-123-4447",
  "website": "ramiro.info",
  "company": {
    "name": "Romaguera-Jacobson",
    "catchPhrase": "Face to face bifurcated interface",
    "bs": "e-enable strategic applications"
  }
  }
  ]

  let numberMatch
  const testing = datas.map(data => {
  if (data.address.match(/#[0-9]+/)) {
    numberMatch = data.address.match(/#[0-9]+/)[0]
    numberMatch = `<a href=${data.website}> ${numberMatch} </a>`
  }
  return (
    <div>
      <p>id: {data.id}</p>
      <p>name: {data.name}</p>
      <p>address: {data.address}</p>
      <p>website: {numberMatch}</p>
    </div>
  )
 })
```

In the first code, since numberMatch is an object, we are converting it to an array and then taking the first value. In the second code, we are directly taking the data on the basis of the index of the required value. You can check the format of numberMatch in the first code using **console.log(numberMatch)** . I hope it helps.